# Entity Framework 4.3 Object graph updates

Tags: entity-framework

I have an object OrderDetail. This has an ID, List of product objects and a shipping detail object.

The order detail and shipping details are new, the products are not ie they already exist in the database.

My problem is that when I do context.savechanges() the products are added into the database ie duplicated.

Is there anyway I can mark the products as 'don't insert just use the ID'?

I don't really want to change my model to say each product has an order detail as (1) this is wrong logically and (2) will likely cause performance issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can mark the products as 'don't insert just use the ID'?

Yes but you must handle it yourselves:

```
dbContext.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
foreach(var product in orderDetail.Products) {
    dbContext.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}    
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```